# Rounding SQL server Select within bigger query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to round off a result in a query (1 column out of many)

```
Select *  (DocTotal - Vat) * Rate AS TOTAL, ItemCode, Qty
From 
ORDR
```

above is my select statement (from within a bigger view)

```
Doctotal is a decimal 20,2

Vat is a decimal 20,2
```

and

```
Rate is decimal 2,4
```

(The other columns aren't in question)

this returns a result as TOTAL with 6 decimal places, eg `353.690000`

is it possible to round the result that is calculated to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Of course you can round....just like nearly every language. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql. You will need to cast/convert if you want this returned with only decimal places.

Comment: decimals *retain* their trailing zeroes even after rounding. `353.690000` is already rounded to 2 decimal digits. Calling `ROUND(,2)` on it would return the same result

Answer (score 2):

Casting it to a decimal will implicitly round the resulting float value from the calculation.

```sql
select *, 
cast((DocTotal - Vat) * Rate as decimal(20,2)) AS TOTAL,
ItemCode, Qty
from ORDR
```

So first rounding it with [ROUND](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp) isn't actually required.

Or you could use [CONVERT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) instead, if you prefere that syntax.
Works the same way in this case.  But it's specific to SQL Server.
While [CAST](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) is a standard feature ([SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92)).

```
convert(decimal(20,2), (DocTotal - Vat) * Rate) AS TOTAL
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for, I found the cast in the docs link from above bout couldnt get the syntax right. Thankyou